# SpringMVC Returning a List Of Objects With JSON

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have two select options and i would like when the user selects one option that other is populated with data from the database. However i am having issues in getting the object list returned to the view.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="getCrimeTypeList.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody List<CrimeType> getCrimeTypeList(@RequestParam(value="crimeCatId") Integer crimeCatId) throws Exception{              

        try {
            List<CrimeType> crimeTypeList = this.crimeTypeManager.getCrimeTypeList(crimeCatId);

             return crimeTypeList;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
}
```

**JQuery**

```
 $("select#offenceCatId").change(function(){

       $.ajax({
           type:'GET',
           url:'getCrimeTypeList.htm',
           data:{crimeCatId: $(this).val()},

            headers: {
             Accept: 'application/json'
            },
           dataType: 'json',

           success:function(data){

            alert('it worked');

           }

       });
     });
```

**HTML**

```
<li>
 <label>Offence Type</label>
 <form:select path="offenceTypeId" id="offenceTypeId" title="Offence Type">
 <form:options items="${crimeType.crimeTypeList}" itemValue="crimeTypeId" itemLabel="crimeTypeDesc"/>
 </form:select>
 <form:errors path="offenceTypeId" class="errors" />
</li>
```

**Error**

```
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCrimeTypeList.htm?[object%20Object]"
```

**EDITED**
I did some experimentation and found if the Controller is returning a String it works however once its returning an Object i am having the issues stated.

**FireBug**

```
GET http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCrimeTypeList.htm?crimeCatId=6 406 Not Acceptable

Response Headers
Content-Length  1067
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Fri, 29 Mar 2013 00:58:17 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1

Request Headers
Accept  application/json
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Host    localhost:8084
Referer http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/crime_registration.htm
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Do you have any exceptions there?

Comment: Until you have provided details of issues (wrong behaviour, exceptions etc.) I'd like to tell, what is in the top of my head: we faced, that regardless what accept-type you're providing, if you have extension `*.htm` or `*.html` on your resource's URL, you won't be getting JSON. Please try to change your URL into f.e. `getCrimeTypeList.json` or without extension at all.

Comment: Since you use mvc then everything will be ok, what you should do is telling me what the problem is plz?

Comment: question updated error included

Comment: Have you tried hitting the url in browser? is it returning correctly?

Comment: @n1ckolas i took your advice and i am getting the following error either way i try with a .json extension or without any at all. Error:NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCrimeTypeList?[object%20Object]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly please make sure your Spring version is 3.1.1 release and you have added jackson.jar in you lib, then try using below code, your code has something reduntant.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getCrimeTypeList.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<CrimeType> getCrimeTypeList(@RequestParam(value="crimeCatId") Integer crimeCatId) throws Exception{    
            try {
                return this.crimeTypeManager.getCrimeTypeList(crimeCatId);
                //return "true";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
}
```

```javascript
$("select#offenceCatId").change(function(){
        var param={crimeCatId:$(this).val()};
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'getCrimeTypeList.htm',
            data:param,
            success:function(data){
                //append options to list
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: I am getting the following error : ""NetworkError: 406 Not Acceptable - http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCrimeTypeList.htm?crimeCatId=5""

Comment: Which version of your Spring? several release of Spring has this issue.

Comment: @QQJF i am using spring version 3.1

Comment: Ok, if you can please use the version 3.1.1 release, I helped another guy solve this issue yesterday whose version is Spring 3.2

Comment: hey sorry i am using 3.1.1 release

Comment: i am going to update my code in the question i am getting a new error

Comment: And did you add jackson.jar in your lib?

Comment: I added jackson.jar and it works thank you so much can you update your answer so i can accept it

Comment: have updated. It's my pleasure that can give you my suggestion.

Comment: is there any way i can keep in contact with you dood?

Comment: Facebook or Twitter: diaozhanming@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Your controller is expecting an request header `Accept=application/json`, in your case you are not setting it.

Try setting the `Accept` header

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'getCrimeTypeList.htm',
        data:{crimeCatId:$(this).val()},
        processData:false,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){


            //append options to list


        }

    });
```

Comment: I am getting the following error "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCrimeTypeList.htm?[object%20Object]"

Comment: do you have jackson library in your classpath